# iOS Objective-C NSURLSession not updating UI / property

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlsession

I'm having some trouble updating my UI in my Objective-C iOS app.

Im calling my function *fetchData* in the *viewDidLoad* section of my ViewController.

The `NSURLSession` succesfully fetches the data however I am unable to update the titleText property in my UI even though its on the main queue.

I can update property in the viewDidLoad method, So I have a feeling this is something to do with the asynchronous request.

However I have tried multiple ways with no luck so any help would be much appreciated.

```
- (void) fetchData
{    
    NSString *strURl = @"www.url.com";
    NSLog(@"%@",strURl);

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURl]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                if (data == nil) {
                    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"error", nil)message:NO_CONNECTION_TEXT preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ok", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
                    [alertController addAction:ok];
                    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

                    return ;
                }
                else
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                        if (!parsedDetails){
                            parsedDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        }

                        parsedDetails = [provider parseJSON:data into:parsedDetails withResponse:response];
                        NSLog(@"%@",parsedDetails);

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            NSLog(@"%@",parsedDetails);
                            NSLog(@"%@",[parsedDetails valueForKey:@"title"]);
                            self.titleText = [parsedDetails valueForKey:@"title"];
                        });
                    });
                }

            }] resume];
}
```

Comment: Where are you updating UI is this code ?

Comment: Whats the UI issue that you are facing? Label not displayed or Alert not displayed or whatelse?

Comment: self.titleText = [parsedDetails valueForKey:@"title"];

Comment: My issue is that the Label is not displayed. if I use _titleText = @"Some Text"; in the viewDidLoad method it is correctly updated.

Comment: What is the value of `[parsedDetails valueForKey:@"title"];`? If it is nil, it won't update.

Comment: the value prints from the line above prints as ("About")

even if I change the code to self.titleText = @“Test”; the label is still blank

Comment: You're only updating `self.titleText`, shouldn't you update the text of the label instead?

Comment: why are you doing networking in the `–viewDidLoad` at the first place? it is much better if you start any operation _after_ the view has gone into the navigation stack, you also have a much better chance (=100%) to update visual components what related to the operation. otherwise you'd just create a pointless race condition.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - Sorry Im pretty new to this, should I instead be running this code in the previous view controller maybe as part of prepareForSegue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1: Determining the title**

`parsedDetails` is a `NSMutableArray` in your code.

Then you are using the KVC (Key-Value Coding) method `valueForKey` on that array.

But that does return a new array. What happens there: the value of the `title` property for each element in the original array (`parsedDetails`) is inserted as a new element in a new array which is finally returned as array.

Due to your comment above:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[parsedDetails valueForKey:@"title"]);
```

gives the return value (an array with one string):

```
("About")
```

But what you actually want is the title element of the first entry, so rather something like this:

```
Detail *detail = parsedDetails.firstObject;
if (detail) {
    title = [detail title];
} else {
    title = @"default empty title";
}
```

Or if you prefer the KVC variant:

```
id detail = parsedDetails.firstObject;
if (detail) {
    title = [detail valueForKey:@"title"];
} else {
    title = @"default empty title";
}
```

**Part 2: Updating the label**

As far as I understand your comments, you have a `NSString` property called `titleText`? Presumably defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSString *titleText;
```

And you also have somewhere a `UILabel` outlet?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

If you just update the local string it will not be reflected in the UI. You yet have to transfer it to the label.

This would look like so:

```
self.label.text = self.titleText;
```

Comment: Thank you very much I think this solves part of my problem. but even if I manually set the value using self.titleText = @"About"; the label dosen't update from my function.

Comment: You are welcome. Regarding the label update: assuming you have a string property and a UILabel outlet: just updating the local string property is not sufficient. You also need to update the label (UILabel has a property called _text_). I've updated the answer.

Comment: correct I have a property of: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titleText;`
but I also have the following code :
`cell.lblTitle.text = [_titleText stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];`
However I don’t think this is the problem though because if I set:
`self.titleText = @"About";`
in viewDidLoad the UI correctly updates to About.

Comment: You have pointed me in the right direction and just realised my mistake I didn't have tableView reloadData at the end of my request.

Comment: Thanks for the Part 1 of the answer as well very helpful.